# MS Access: Combobox Truncating Leading Zeros when using DLookup

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am attempting to set the value of a combobox via a DLookup call, that is inside of a related textbox's Change sub.

The issue I am having is that during the DLookup call, the leading zero that is present on many of my strings (document ids) that I am searching for is being removed from the combobox, prior to calling its own Change sub.

My code looks like this:

```
Private Sub txtImport_Change()
Dim id As String
Me.txtImport.SetFocus
id = Me.txtImport.Text
Me.cboId.SetFocus
Me.cboId.Text = DLookup(id,"DocumentTable")
cboId_Change
End Sub
```

---

For background,

I am doing this to auto-populate a new form based on a value selected on a previous form. Form #2 is going to be an in-depth informational form about a specific document that is selected on Form #1.

The driving control on the new form (which can be done manually, if the user chooses to skip Form #1), is via the combobox: **cboId**'s selection. I would like to keep this functionality for the below use-case.

So, in the use-case where a user is utilizing Form #1, I am trying to set cboId's value on Form #2 via a DLookup on a string that is being passed between the two forms (the docId selected in Form #1 is sent to txtImport on Form #2 when that form loads after a button press).

Comment: Is id set to a field name? Is the field a number type? If yes, then the leading zeros are only a format setting because numbers cannot have leading zeros. And if cboId is bound to a number field, again numbers cannot have leading zeros. Format to display with leading zeros.

Comment: Domain aggregate function must specify field to search in as well as table/query to use. Your function is not using WHERE argument so cannot be confident expected value will be retrieved.

Comment: @June7 You are absolutely correct. It seems that the question I should of been asking is "What is proper DLookup syntax".
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is issue resolved? Many tutorials about domain aggregate functions.

Comment: Yes, I was able to resolve the issue after fixing my DLookup implementation. Thank you